# printing but need image name

Tags: c#, printing

I am trying to print a single tiff file with multiple frames. However if I use javascript (window.print()) i get a print out of the entire webpage and not just the tiff image.

So I looked around StackOverflow and found some sample code. I was trying to implement it however the problem is the that the code works for an absolute image URL :- such as  "C:\img.jpeg"

***I am wondering if anyone can show me how to transform my imgFax.ImageUrl to an actual image name? (otherwise I get an error:- "Illegal character in path" <--- in my  System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imgFax.ImageUrl); code)***

If anyone can show me some sample code that would be amazing! Thanks.

```
protected void PrintAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  // number of frames 
  int number = _FaxPages.Count; 


 // for loop to iterate through each frame 
 for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) 
  { 
     // fax ID 
     string _FaxId = Page.Request["FaxId"]; 

     //string _Frame = Page.Request["Frame"]; 

     // current frame 
     _PageIndex = i; 

     // IMG URL 
     imgFax.ImageUrl = "ShowFax.ashx?n=" + _FaxId + "&f=" + _PageIndex + "&mw=750"; 



     PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument(); 

     pd.PrintPage += PrintPage; 
     pd.Print();   

 }
```

}

```
private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e) 
{ 
   System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imgFax.ImageUrl); 
   Point loc = new Point(100, 100); 
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc); 
}
```

Comment: take a look at these 2 articles and see if this can help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680485/printing-but-need-image-name
http://en.csharp-online.net/Graphics%2C_Multimedia%2C_and_Printing_Recipes%E2%80%94Recipe_8_15

Comment: the tag says C# and I know that this is not javascript..didn't say it was?

Comment: You state this in your question  However if I use javascript i get a print out of the entire webpage and not just the tiff image.

Comment: yeah there is a "if".. which means if I try to use the javascript functionality :- window.print()... but I am not, since it is not working. But thank you very much for the links, checkign them out.

Comment: Not a problem.. just confuses others when you imply that you have with the word IF or is that Inference..LOL I always get the 2 messed up..but anyway. perhaps you could refactor the question.. :)

Comment: by the way... there is only 1 article.. the other article seems to be a direct link to this article itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you can at all do any printing in ASP via PrintDocument. This is all server-side code, while the printing is to be done at - **and by** the client's browser. I think that you will have to do it via JavaScript, but to not print the entire page - you will have to create another page that will only present the contents to be printed, then redirect the user to that smaller page (for example in a popup window) and then auto-print it via javascript. I;m not 100% sure, but all banking sites I use seem to follow that, and this is quite common in general..

For example, here's an article with this exact approach: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=92

just remember that your small 'print-page' should actually display the things you want to print :)

another nice link on printing images: http://forums.asp.net/post/3369436.aspx

Comment: so from what I can gather... I have to somehow create a new image, everytime my for loop iterates thru each single frame on the FAX image. Then print these images...am I seeing this eye-to-eye with you?

Comment: Yes, I as thinking abot something close. Start with the last link I've provided and start small - just try putting it all together so that the IMG tag (inside that popup window) displays your 'ShowFax.aspx?....' url contents. It will probably display and print only the first page - but it's ok for starters. Note that the popup displays and prints simple HTML - so you just have to provide vertically more IMGs with consecutive image-pages

Comment: and how exactly do I replace ImageURL in the following line:-

   printWindow.document.write("<img id='img' src='" + document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_ImgMyPhoto').src + "'/>");

Comment: 'ctl00_MainContent_ImgMyPhoto'

what does ct100_MainContent stand for? 

because in the code from the link the image is defined as:-

asp:Image ID="ImgMyPhoto" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="90px" />

Comment: You've probaly noticed that this line dynamically builds a HTML code. Just remove the "document.getelement..." code and provide there your own URL to the image instead. The document.getElementById is a javascript function to search through the DOM tree for an html-element with given id. However, you must provide the actual final ID that is emitted to browser. The ID specified was ctl00_MainContent_ImgMyPhoto -- this is how ASP mangles the names of components so there are no collisions. Look how they named their component ID=ImgMyPhoto. It probably lies on "MainContent" on some UserControl

Comment: All ASP controls can be assigned an ID - but that ID is "scoped" to the current document. If you place 50 such controls on a page and every one of that controls create a small label with ID="textlabel", how do the page js code differentiate between them? This is why the IDs are mangled. First control would get ctl00_textlabel, next would get ctl01_textlabel, ..., then las ctl49_textlabel and similar thing happens for all controls. This is why all ASP controls also provide a ClientID property - ID is the 'local/scoped name' and ClientID is the 'final/mangled name'.

Comment: So, if you have an image tag out there, you may either just replace the expression with a correct URL, or you can use myImg.ClientID to provide your own correct Javascript ID for the getElementById function, i.e.:  `...src='" + document.getElementById('<%=myImgControl.ClientID%>').src + "'/>...`

Answer (score 0):

You could split the single tiff image into separate files, as demonstrated [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/51ba8a7e-fce0-47f3-800c-102295f50c6d), then you could have a unique URL for each image:

```
static String[] SplitFile(String file_name)
{
    System.Drawing.Image imageFile = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file_name);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension frameDimensions = new System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension(imageFile.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
    int NumberOfFrames = imageFile.GetFrameCount(frameDimensions);
    string[] paths = new string[NumberOfFrames];
    for (int intFrame = 0; intFrame < NumberOfFrames; ++intFrame)
    {
        imageFile.SelectActiveFrame(frameDimensions, intFrame);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imageFile);
        paths[intFrame] = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\" + intFrame.ToString() + ".tif";
        bmp.Save(paths[intFrame], System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
        bmp.Dispose();
    }
    imageFile.Dispose();
    return paths;
}
```

Comment: note that implicit assumption that his web page will have to be capable of **saving** the bitmaps directly to the drive.. May be not granted for some hosting sites! Not mentioning the problems with file bookkeeping like watching for duplicates, removing unused after some time etc.. this is not-so-good approach. It's better to create small page that provides that images dynamically, depending on query- or session-parameters. This is quite simple thing to do, just remember about setting the content-type and to disable rendering of aspx tags

Comment: see that is what I am thinking that needs to be done//. split the file into seprate images and then print these images one-by-one. 

However the files are fax docs in a queue...the user selects the queue and is presented by file list...gridview...selects one of the file and that file is displayed...

However I am not sure how in the Static String splitfile function I can get that filename?? 

I am only storing it as FaxID...

Comment: please check my comment. You seem to be having lots of files - they will pollute your drives and you'll make yourself more work, because you will have to implement bookkeeping for all those files

Comment: About the filename - Dan somewhat oddly assumed that you have the file on drive already. See how the first line of that method reads the image "from file".. This will not help you much

Comment: You could just save each separate file into a new folder, and then after printing delete the entire new folder.

Comment: and how will he detect when the printing is COMPLETED? and that the user did not cancel it? and what if the user went for coffe and forgot or got hit by a bus? of course, you can flush it after session expires, if you add detection for it. But all that just adds more somewhat precise work to be done, while making simple image-viewing page is a 10-minute copy-paste task.

Comment: @user1683846: I've added one more link, please see it for sure, it gives exact way to quickly make a popup with image printing. Just need to replace URL in that IMG tag inside for your image

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted.  @user1683846 - what does the URL load in a browser?  Does it show just the main image, or the individual page for the .tiff file?  I assumed that since you were using the method Image.FromFile that your real problem was having the entire .tiff file and not being able to print each page separately.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, ok.. I know I already answered something, but I've noticed that you've marked the question bold.. So here it is: YOU CANNOT, there is NO WAY.

Url that you have that points to the image is just an internet link. It might point to the image, or to a website, or to some binary data. The remote webserver reads the URL parameters and decides what to do with it. There is no file name at all. Only URL of the webpage "ShowFax.ashx" and its parameters.

Some webpages may return you a special header, content-disposition/attachement, and in that header they may sometimes provide you with a filename. This is how "download" webpages provide the information to the browser so it may display a "Save file as.." window to the user. However, it probably is not the case. You are displaying the image in a aspx control that simply reads the image from an URL. It is all automated by the control, so you do not even have chance to peek the headers -- of course, unless you manually send the request, capture the stream, peek, redirect it back to the control, etc. IMHO, too much job for simple task of printing, and that would be only the beginning!